# pm2 node module is not reading any environment variable from current bash instance

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables, pm2

I am trying to run my express application using the pm2 module. The module works fine but all the environment variables defined in the bash session are not defined in the server initiated by pm2.

If I write `echo $URL` in my terminal instance it would print `http://ec2-51-20-6-22.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

However, if I run `pm2 start dist/index.js` it can't access `process.env.URL` and `console.log(process.env.URL)` logs undefined.

Furthermore, If I run `node dist/index.js` it can access all environment variables and `console.log(process.env.URL)` logs `http://ec2-51-20-6-22.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com`.

What should I do to make pm2 access my instance environment variables? Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Your `echo` doesn't really tell much. For checking the environment variable, do a `printenv URL`.

Comment: Furthermore, is it ensured that `pm2` starts the application as its child process? I don't know about `pm2`, so I can't tell.

Comment: Yep, `printenv` show URL successfully

Comment: Great. So at least we know that `pm2` is not propagating the environment to the processes it manages. It looks to me as this is a problem about how to operate and configure pm2, and not about node2 programming. Perhaps it would be better to ask this at [so]?